# Check if a specific word is in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task to write code in python that will check if a word is anywhere in the DataFrame. I did with the regex function, but the result is not correct, because it only finds a match in the column names, not in the rows. If anyone can help me, i will be grateful!

```
import re
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Snowflake_databases\DRAGANA_DB\Dragana_db_information.csv')

for i in df:
      x=re.match('TABLE.*', i)
      if x:
       print(i)
```

Comment: Can you provide example data to reproduce your question, please?

Comment: When you loop `for i in df` it goes through every column name. You'll need to loop through the rows like `for i in range(len(df))...` and then filter by `i`. Also, try use `str.extract()` from Pandas.

Comment: ```for i in df:``` will iterate over the column index of your dataframe, not the data itself.

Comment: IIUC, you could try `df.stack().str.contains('Table.*').unstack().any(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.loc:

```
df.loc[df.values=='YourWordHere']
```

or if you have a list of words and you want to make a new dataframe with only rows containing those words:

```
l = ['Words', 'to', 'search']
cat = pd.DataFrame()

for w in l:
    result = df.loc[df.values==w]
    cat = pd.concat([cat, result])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to find words in particular Column in which you wanna search.

```
import csv

csvfile = open("C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Snowflake_databases\DRAGANA_DB\Dragana_db_information.csv")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    if "Table" in row["<Column Name>"]:
        print row
```

If you want to find that word in entire row. Use following code

```
import csv

csvfile = open("C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Snowflake_databases\DRAGANA_DB\Dragana_db_information.csv")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    if "Table" in str(row):
        print row
```